# If I buy a game I previously sold, will my data still be there?

Tags: ps4, mortal-kombat-x

So a year ago I sold my MkXL, and now I am not a fan of Mk11, so I was thinking of swapping my PS4 Spiderman for it. Will I keep my data because I previously owned it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will, as long as you are using the same account that you used previously.